# Why is this function I made cliaming that log(4) is complex

Tags: python, math

I was making a class for logarithims of different bases and I noticed certain numbers like log(2) and log(4) were coming up as complex

```
class LogBaseN:
  def __init__(self,base):
    self.base = base

  def __call__(self,x):
    y,I = sp.symbols("y I")
    self.x = x
    if self.x == 1:
      return 0
      pass
    if type(self.x) == int or type(self.x) == float:
      ans = sp.solve(sp.Eq(self.base,self.x**(1/y)))[0]
      try:
        if int(ans) == float(ans):
          return int(eval(str(ans)))
        else:
          return float(eval(str(ans)))
        return ans
      except:
        return(eval(str(ans)))
    if type(self.x) == list:
      answers = []
      for num in self.x:
        i = num
        if i == 1:
          answers.append(0)
          continue
        ans = sp.solve(sp.Eq(self.base,i**(1/y)))[0]
        try:
          if int(ans) == float(ans):
            answers.append(int(eval(str(ans))))
          else:
            answers.append(float(eval(str(ans))))
        except:
          answers.append(ans)
    return answers
ln = LogBaseN(e)
log2 = LogBaseN(2)
Log = LogBaseN(10)
print(Log(4))
#Output log(2)/(3.14159265359*I + log(sqrt(10)))
```

I tried evaluating in by using str() then evaling using eval but that didnt fix it just to make it output I had to use sympy.symbols so the "I" would not cause an error

Comment: When I try to run the posted code, I get `name 'e' is not defined` and `name 'sp' is not defined`.  It's hard to evaluate code that won't run.

Comment: `4 to the power (1/y)` does result in 10, though, for `y = log(2)/(π i + log (sqrt(10))`. There are infinitely many complex solutions to such type of exponential equations; `e to the power of (2 π i)` is equal to 1; multiples of `π i` can appear somewhere while still satisfying the original equation.